# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: There is already an object named 'sysnsobjs' in the database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

Tags: sql-server

I am getting SQL restore error , please help.

Im using Managment studio. Im trying to restore my database(say for example database name XYZ) taken backup from SQL 2000 server and trying to restore to 2008 R2 database XYZ. The exact error string is during Restore failed is

Restore failed for Server 'MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617.0+((KJ_RTM_GDR).110422-1125+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseOptions.RunRestore()

===================================

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: There is already an object named 'sysnsobjs' in the database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)**

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1617.0+((KJ_RTM_GDR).110422-1125+)&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQueryWithMessage(StringCollection queries, ServerMessageEventHandler dbccMessageHandler, Boolean errorsAsMessages)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv

> ODBC SQL server Driver ERROR There is a already an object named
>   'sysnobjs'  in database

While restoring SQL Server 2000 user database to SQL Server 2008 R2 version.

Please let me know whether Microsoft SQL Server 2000 database backup and restore it to SQL Server 2008 is allowed?

If it is not so , is there any work-around for this issue?

Comment: Can you **show us the SQL** command(s) that you're using??

Comment: Are you trying to restore with Management Studio while the 'master' database is selected?

Comment: No. Im trying to restore user database taken backup from 2000 to 2008 using managment studio

Answer (score 0):

In options, while you are in the box that has you choose where your backup is to restore, choose overwrite existing database option. That should get rid of that error and allow you to restore that backup.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the Backup File to restore in the General Tab, Go to the Options Tab.

Select "Överwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)"

Then, in the "Restore the database files as:" Table, Go to the [Restore As] column

Notice the string in the first row (for Data) and the string in the second row (for Images) are exactly the same. This will result in some errors.

Change the string in the first row to something else (like adding a date), for example

C:................\YourFileName.mdf

C:................\YourFileName20151124.mdf

Problem solved

Here's my full Script:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Makhado_Indigents] FROM  DISK = N'C:\IndiCheck\Makhado_Indigents.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'New_Indigents' 
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INDICHECK\MSSQL\DATA\Makhado_Indigents.mdf',  
MOVE N'New_Indigents_Images' 
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INDICHECK\MSSQL\DATA\Makhado_Indigents1.mdf',  
MOVE N'New_Indigents_log' 
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INDICHECK\MSSQL\DATA\Makhado_Indigents.ldf',  
MOVE N'New_Indigents_Docs' 
TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INDICHECK\MSSQL\DATA\Makhado_Indigents.New_Indigents_Docs',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO
```

You may also need to Switch Filestreaming on by running the following script:

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2 RECONFIGURE
```

Restart the server:

Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager

Right Click on the Server and select Restart